# Google Sheets Script - Search in Arrays and Replace Values in Next Column

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

For some reason I'm not really able to perform a trivial search and replace in google script (using google sheets).

What I want to do is

1. Read values form an array in Sheet1
2. Find the value in a 2D-array in sheet2 (two columns). When the value is found, the script adds '+1' to the value in the column next to the found value in sheet 2.
3. Repeat for the next value in sheet1

Assume I have a value "Muse" in Sheet 1. I want to search for "Muse" in sheet two and if the column next to this value has already a 1, it should add one and write it back. That's it. Then do the same with the next value in sheet1.

I searched for similar scripts but was unfortunately not able to adapt something to my needs.

Edit: It's driving me nuts, this is what I have at the moment:

```
function findingReplacing()
{
  var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var sh2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet2');
  var searchfor = sh1.getRange('B2').getValues();
  var replacewith = sh2.getDataRange().getValues();

  for(var i=1;i<replacewith.length;i++)
  {
    if(replacewith[i][0]==searchfor)
    {
      replacewith[i][1]=1;
    }
  }
  //sheet2.SetValues(replacewith);
  sh2.setValues(replacewith);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? If you post your code we can see where you might be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

just answered it myself: this works:

```
function findingReplacing()
{
  var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var sh2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet2');
  var CustDunned = sh1.getRange('B2').getValues();
  var range = sh2.getRange("A:B");
  var rangeA = range.getValues()

  for(var i=1;i<rangeA.length;i++)
  {
    if(rangeA[i][0]==CustDunned)
    {
      rangeA[i][1]=rangeA[i][1]+1;
    }
  }
  range.setValues(rangeA);
}
```